# RatingBar - When touch the RatingBar the stars get all filled up

Tags: android

Im working with a native RatingBar and i am having only one problem.

I have 5 stars, starting all of them empty. When i touch on star (or swipe my finger across the rating bar) the 5 stars get selected and the real rate shows up after i separate my finger of the screen.

Why is this happening?

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:rating="5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtitle"/>
```

Image 1: Here i am with my finger on the screen in the star number 3
Image 2: An here i am now with my finger off the screen

[image: Here i am with my finger on the screen in the star number 3]

[image: An here i am now with my finger off the screen]

Answer (score 0):

Add below line inside `<RatingBar>`

```
android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
```